# Can't finish execution by complete when user leave the app

Tags: java, android, quit

I need to stop all that my app is doing (like vibrating) after the user quit the aplication, how can i do that ?  My app vibrate the phone for certain amount of time that the user choose, but if the user start, and quit the app .. the cellphone continues to vibrate for the time chosen.. How can i treat this error ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText tempo;
    Button bt;
    Thread t;
    int estado = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tempo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tempo);
        //long delay = Long.parseLong(tempo.getText().toString());

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btvibrar);

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (!tempo.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                    if (estado == 1) {

                        Vibrar();
                        estado *= -1;

                        bt.setText("Parar !");
                        bt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                        //Handler handler = new Handler();
                        //handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        //@Override
                        //public void run() {
                        //estado*=-1;
                        //bt.setText("Vibrar !");
                        //bt.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        //}
                        //  },  );
                    } else {
                        Parar();
                        estado *= -1;
                        bt.setText("Vibrar !");
                        bt.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                   }
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    dialogo.setTitle("Erro !");
                    dialogo.setMessage("Escolha um tempo.");
                    dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                    dialogo.show();

                }
            }

            private void Vibrar() {    // É necessario lançar excessao no ANDROIDMANIFEST.XML
                Vibrator rr = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                long treal = Long.parseLong(tempo.getText().toString());
                long milliseconds = treal * 1000;
                rr.vibrate(milliseconds);
            }

            private void Parar() {
                Vibrator rr = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                rr.cancel();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to differentiate between quitting, and pausing the application(a pause happens if another application comes to the foreground). Secondly, you need to override the appropriate methods to handle what happens when the application is paused or destroyed.

For example, overriding

```
protected void onPause() {}
```

will allow you to define what should happen when the application is paused, hence, you can gracefully stop whatever your application is doing.

Similarly, you can implement `onStop` and `onDestroy` if needed. But in your case, I believe `onStop` and `onPause` will be sufficient :)

Also, try giving this page a look, it gives a detailed description of the activity lifecycle 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: Find a "Bug" , after using `OnPause()` and `Onstop()`  and quit the app, the vibration ends... BUT when i quit and block my phone, to unblock the phone use the vibrator, and the phone "remember" the last time i choose to vibrate... and starts ! How to end the vibrator ( and buffer ? ) completely  ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop vibration service in `onStop()` of your activity.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
            Vibrator rr = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            rr.cancel();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `onPause` to your ativity and cancel the vibrator from there:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    Parar();
}
```

This will stop the vibrator when your activity goes to foreground and another activity comes up (e.g. an incoming phone call while your activity is in foreground).  This may be a more desirable behaviour than cancelling the vibrator only when the app finishes.